# Display youtube iframe if url stored in mySQL

Tags: mysql, url, if-statement, iframe, youtube

I created a form where we can register youtube embed url in a post.
I'd like to display the iframe only if an url has been register for this post.

I made this code to display the report information :

```
<?php

$req = $db->query('SELECT id, title, author, category, date_event, country, city, content, tag, youtube FROM report ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT 0, 10');

while ($data = $req->fetch())
{
?>

<div class="news">
      <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['title']); ?></h3>
      <p>Author: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['author']); ?></p>
            <p>Category : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['category']); ?></p>
            <p>Date of the event : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['date_event']); ?></p>
            <p>Country : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['country']); ?></p>
            <p>City : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['city']); ?></p>
            <p class="display_list"><?php echo html_entity_decode($data['content'], ENT_HTML5 , 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
            <p>Tag : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['tag']); ?></p>
        <p>Youtube : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['youtube']); ?></p>
        <p>
            <?php
            $youtube=$data['youtube'];

            if($youtube==1){
                echo "<p>display iframe</p>";
            }else{
            {
                    echo "<p>don't display iframe</p>";
                }
            }        
            ?>
        </p>
```

The request to display url with  works correctly. the urls are displayed if they are contained in the row.

However the condition code displays the same answers for all the posts : "don't display iframe".

The condition statement for $youtube variable is certainly not right but I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: have you checked the values of your `$youtube` variable directly?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am bit new in php, how can I do this verification?

Comment: @hoijui, I checked the values and they are displayed correctly with : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['youtube']); ?>

Comment: obviously (hopefully) you are now using an adjusted code then the one shown in your question (at least with the suggestion of madhu in his answer). so you do also not get the same results. you have to always be very clear what you are trying right now, and what happens/goes wrong. "is not correct" is not clear enough! take your time to make sure that what you present here to us is well done, clear, specific, minimal, sufficient and your latest state. you want something for us, you have to present it to us on the silver plate, fulfilling all our wishes, even the ones we did not know about. ;-)

Comment: @hoijui, sorry I guess my last comment was not really useful.

Comment: @hoijui, sorry I guess my last comment was not really useful. I indeed added the suggestion of madhu. And to check the $youtube values I added this code : <p>Youtube : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['youtube']); ?></p>. the registered url are displayed correctly and the empty row remains empty. However the instructions provided by madhusoodan prabhu have the same results than previously : 'display iframe'. I hope this answer is clearer. thank you for your patience

Comment: so `$youtube` now contains a URL, but it is still `== 1`? that does not make sense. it would really make sense if you post your current code as it is now, if you cant edit your question, post it here in a comment (and someone else can put it into your question)

Comment: @hoijui, I updated the code in the post, thanks

Comment: if `$youtube` is supposed to contain a URL, and it does so as you say why do you check it for `== 1` still? you have to know how the value of youtube looks when there is no URL, and check for that value.

Comment: Ok so I changed the condition if($youtube==1) by if(! $youtube). So the empty rows displays 'don't display iframe' and the filled rows displays 'display iframe'. So it works correctly now. Thank you a lot for the advises @madhusoodan prabhu and @hoijui!

Comment: ahh good! :-) (you may want to up-vote usefull comments and answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you have assigned $youtube=1; instead of $youtube=$data['youtube']; in the code

try this 

<?php

$req = $db->query('SELECT id, title, author, category, date_event, country, city, content, tag, youtube FROM report ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT 0, 10');

while ($data = $req->fetch())
{
?>

<div class="news">
      <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['title']); ?></h3>
      <p>Author: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['author']); ?></p>
            <p>Category : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['category']); ?></p>
            <p>Date of the event : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['date_event']); ?></p>
            <p>Country : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['country']); ?></p>
            <p>City : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['city']); ?></p>
            <p class="display_list"><?php echo html_entity_decode($data['content'], ENT_HTML5 , 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
            <p>Tag : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['tag']); ?></p>
            <p>

            <?php
$youtube=$data['youtube'];

if($youtube==1){
    echo "<p>display iframe</p>";
}else{
{
        echo "<p>don't display iframe</p>";
    }
}        
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is still not correct. is there a way to check espcially that $youtube row contains an url?